# Parameterized FileSelector / FileInput read excel file

Tags: python, parameters, base64, panel

I am attempting to set up a panel app that includes a FileInput button. I can not manage to get the uploaded file read by pn.widgets.FileInput properly.

```
class try_upload(param.Parameterized):
    fileselector = param.FileSelector()
    file_input_df = param.DataFrame()
    
    def __init__(self,**params):
        super().__init__(**params)
        self.fileselector_widget = pn.Param(self.param.fileselector),
        self.file_input_df_widget = pn.Param(self.param.file_input_df),
        self._layout = pn.Row(pn.Param(self,parameters=['fileselector','file_input_df']
                                      ),
                              pn.Param(widgets={'fileselector': pn.widgets.FileInput(accept='.xlsx,.xls',multiple=True)
                                              }
                                      ),
                              self.file_input_df_widget,
                              width=1,
                              sizing_mode='fixed'
                             )
        
    @pn.depends('fileselector',watch=True)
    def _updateinput(self):
        if self.fileselector is not None:
            # decode = base64.b64decode(self.fileselector)
            # df = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(decode.decode('utf-8')))
            # self.input_data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decode))
            # self.file_input_df = df
            self.file_input_df = self.fileselector
            self.file_input_df_widget = self.file_input_df
        
    @pn.depends('file_input_df',watch=True)
    def _update_input_widget(self):
        if self.file_input_df is not None:
            self.file_input_df_widget = self.file_input_df
            return pn.widgets.Tabulator(self.file_input_widget_df,width=100)
        
    def __panel__(self):
        return self._layout
        
        
try_upload_class = try_upload(name='upload')
```

```
pn.extension()

app = pn.Row(pn.Column(pn.Param(try_upload_class.param,
                      widgets = {'fileselector': pn.widgets.FileInput(accept='.xlsx,.xls',multiple=True)
                                }
                               )
                     ),
             pn.Column(try_upload_class._updateinput)
            )
app
```

Uploading a file with the button gives:

```
ValueError: DataFrame parameter 'file_input_df' value must be an instance of DataFrame, not [b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00b\xee\x9dh^\x01\x00\x00\x90\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
```

which is essentially a whatever Tornado sends back from the backend if I am not mistaken. Attempting to decode with base64 also fails and using [0] to get the list object out of a list does not work. Thanks for any help in advance.

Expected file to get input into param.DataFrame. Can't decode properly and various methods seem to fail.